# Write something in .txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file

How do I write something in a .txt file using javascript?

I created a variable holding a specific value and now I want to safe it into a .txt file

Comment: *I want to safe it*, am sure you want to *save it*

Comment: Although not a direct answer to your question... you may find this useful background reading: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: You can usee [data url's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in the browser, but in **node.js** you can do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.txt", yourVariable, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: better statement for OP might be ... *you can't do this in browser , but if server is running node.js ....* Keep in mind that someone new and  using another stack may have no idea what node is

Answer (score 1):

Front end languages like JavaScript will not allow you to edit a file like that, for security reasons. However, you should look into Node.js file writer if you really need to write text; it allows you to write in JS but compiles into a C language (I don't remember which one). But this would mean you would need to use a node server, which might not be desired in your case.